# How do I close open internet ports at project level in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In GCP cloud, how can I deny developers from opening  ports to the internet?

Is there a deny policy which can deny users from creating Virtual machines with security  rules which are open to the internet?

Or is there any tool in GCP which can provide AWS config functionality for remediation?

Comment: Are you want to block traffic from the Internat to your VM's or the opposite ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can't close open ports at the project level.

Firewall rules used to control this work on a network (VPC) level.

By default all ingress the traffic to the VM's is blocked and all egress traffic is open. See the "[Implied Firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules)" in the documentation.

This being said - you can revoke Developers' permissions to set up firewall rules ([Network Admin Role](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.networkAdmin)) and do it yourself but this may be very impractical or downright impossible due to the amount of work involved.

Answer (score 0):

You can config the [VPC firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) let you allow or deny connections to or from your virtual machine (VM) instances.